# Should sections be wrapped around article tag?

Tags: html, css

Hey Guys I am beginner at web development and was reading articles on semantic HTML. I have read the article on [semrush.com](https://www.semrush.com/blog/semantic-html5-guide/) concerning the topic which suggests wrapping sections on webpage by article tag. Then wrap article with the main tag and the question is should we do like that or just wrap sections with the main removing article.

Answer (score 4):

## What does article HTML Tag do?

The  element identifies a self-contained piece of content which could theoretically be distributed to other websites and platforms as a stand-alone unit. The  element is a good choice to contain entire blog posts, news articles, and similar content.

Read more: https://html.com/tags/article/#ixzz5inJaVxrn

This is most often used in two contexts:

> On a page with a single piece of content, a single  element
>   can be used to contain the main content and set it off from the rest
>   of the page. On a page with multiple pieces of content (a blog index
>   page, a search results page, a category page, a news feed), multiple
>    elements can be used to contain each individual piece of
>   content. Either way, this is functionally similar to using 
>   elements, and the display and styling work the same. However, using
>   the  element instead of  provides more semantic
>   information to screen readers, search engines, and third-party
>   applications.

[image]

Read more: https://html.com/tags/article/#ixzz5inJRPfTN

```
   <!-- Blog Index Page - Multiple Article Elements --> 
<body> 
    <header> 
        <h1>Title of Site</h1> 
    </header> 
    <main> 
        <article> 
            <header> 
                <h2>Title of Blog Post</h2> 
            </header> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="">Read More.</a></p> 
        </article> 
        <article> 
            <header> 
                <h2>Title of Blog Post</h2>
            </header>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="">Read More.</a></p> 
        </article> 
        <article> 
            <header> 
                <h2>Title of Blog Post</h2>
            </header>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <a href="">Read More.</a></p> 
        </article> 
    </main> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey so it depends what you're doing. Especially for SEO the types of tags you use kind of tell Google and other browsers what your content is.

For example if you were doing a blog then I would wrap each post in an article tag. However if it was just a web page with text that wasn't necessarily an article you can use a section tag as shown here https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_section.asp.